# Force chrome to cache static content like images

Tags: caching, google-chrome-extension

I want to improve my experience with the internet by caching static content like images(jpg,png,gif) and fonts. Because always happens that when watching a webpage with a lot of images, and then I refresh with F5, the same contents are downloaded again.

I know that it's because the response headers could contain no cache o max-age 0, and even sometimes it happens when there is no cache o max-age in the response.

But in case of images or fonts that never change, it's useless to get max-age 0. So I wanted to know if there is a way to override the response headers and set them with max-age 1 year. Maybe with a chrome extension?

Comment: How can you tell a static image from a dynamic image client side. If this was without problems chrome would already be doing this.

Comment: i dont' understand. sorry i'm spanish speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using a Chrome Extension. See this [Change HTTP Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-http-request-heade/ppmibgfeefcglejjlpeihfdimbkfbbnm?hl=en) chrome extension already does it.

For your specific case, you just need to do this:

- Add an event listener which should be called whenever headers are received.
- Read the details of the headers
- Check if response content type is image
- Add/Update the desired header to the headers

To accomplish this you can use  [webRequest Headers Received](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onHeadersReceived) event.
Documentation of onHeadersReceived

> **onHeadersReceived (optionally synchronous)**: Fires each time that an HTTP(S) response header is received. Due to redirects and authentication requests this can happen multiple times per request. This event is intended to allow extensions to add, modify, and delete response headers, such as incoming Set-Cookie headers.

Your code will look something like this

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    for(var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
      // If response is of image, add the cache-control header
    }
    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}, 
{urls: ['https://*/*'], types: ['image'] },
['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

PS: I have not run and tested the code so please excuse the typos.

## EDIT (After @RobW comment)

**No, this is not possible as of now (22 march 2014)**. Adding `Cache-control` has no influence on the caching behavior. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22576102) for more details.

Comment: I did it and in permissions I put this:
"*://*/*.jpg","*://*/*.png", "*://*/*.gif", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"
the function is called because in console I see the headers added, but in the response headers of the images(in their network tabs) it doesn't appear.  And i added 'blocking' in the extraInfoSpec param to make it synchronous

Comment: Well, since there's no other answer, and the theory is correct, then aproved

Comment: But by the way i made another question explaining this problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209359/cache-all-images-with-onheadersreceived

Comment: @BubuDaba Can you please try to put "*://*/*" in permissions instead of individual image paths and then try it.

Comment: Yes I did in the other question but with '<all_urls>'

Comment: `<all_urls>` is fine and it should have worked. Please put an answer to this or your other question (I am watching that using StackEye ;) ) in case you get to know the solution.

Comment: Adding `Cache-control` has no influence on the caching behavior (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22576102). To avoid confusion, please update your answer to state that the requested behavior is not possible.

Comment: @RobW Thanks man..I will update the answer. I really didn't test this as I mentioned in my PS to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit this is an old question, I stumbled upon it recently. Later I found the chrome extension "Speed-Up Browsing" which seems to do exactly what the OP asked for.

For me it worked.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-up-browsing/hkhnldpdljhiooeallkmlajnogjghdfb?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You could use Fiddle https://www.telerik.com/fiddler (free) as proxy adding caching for selected URLs or patterns. I did that a