# Cache all images with onHeadersReceived

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to modify the response headers of the images to save bandwith and improve the response time.These are my files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Cache all images",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "",
    "background": {"scripts": ["cacheImgs.js"]},
    "permissions": [ "<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking" ],
    "icons": {"48": "48.png"},
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**cacheImgs.js**

```
var expDate = new Date(Date.now()+1000*3600*24*365).toUTCString();
var newHeaders =
    [{name : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value : "*"},
    {name : "Cache-Control", value : "public, max-age=31536000"},
    {name : "Expires", value : expDate},
    {name : "Pragma", value : "cache"}];
function handler(details) {   
    var headers = details.responseHeaders;
    for(var i in headers){
        if(headers[i].name.toLowerCase()=='content-type' && headers[i].value.toLowerCase().match(/^image\//)){
            for(var i in newHeaders) {
                var didSet = false;
                for(var j in headers) {                                                                                               
                    if(headers[j].name.toLowerCase() == newHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() ) {
                        headers[j].value = newHeaders[i].value;
                        did_set = true; break;
                    }
                }
                if(!didSet) { headers.push( newHeaders[i] ); } 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(headers);
    return {responseHeaders: headers}
};
var requestFilter = {urls:['<all_urls>'], types: ['image'] };
var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking', 'responseHeaders'];

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(handler, requestFilter, extraInfoSpec);
```

the console.log fires many times and i can see the new headers. The problem is that when I open the chrome developer tools of the page, in the network tab, i see the same original headers of the images. Also note the blocking value in the extraInfoSpec, so that's supposed to be synchronous. Does someone happen the same?

**UPDATE**
Now I see the modified response headers in the network panel.
But now I only see from images whose initiator is the webpage itself. The images whose initiator are jquery.min.js doesn't change the response headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, it turns out my previous answer was wrong.  This is actually a Chrome bug - Chrome's DevTools Network panel will only show the *actual* headers received from the server. However, the headers you've injected will still have the desired effect.

Another extension developer identified the issue [here](http://hexcoder.us/2013/08/08/response-headers-and-chrome-extensions/) and provided a link to the [Chrome defect report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258064)

Answer (score 6):

There are two relevant issues here.

First, the headers displayed in the developer tools are those that are received from the server. Modifications by extensions do not show up (http://crbug.com/258064).

Second (this is actually more important!), modifying the cache headers (such as `Cache-control`) has **no influence** on the caching behavior of Chromium, because the caching directives have already been processed when the webRequest API is notified of the headers.

See http://crbug.com/355232 - "Setting caching headers in webRequest.onHeadersReceived does not influence caching"

Comment: Can you please support your second point with official chrome documentation or add some more explanation.

Comment: @blunderboy There is no documentation. It's all in the source code. That having said, I'm currently writing a bug report with more details. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: The what purpose can be achieved on modifying  the cache headers? Can next request be cached if not the current one?

Comment: @user5858 Nothing happens (w.r.t caching).